# Why is danser not conjugated in "Je regarde Anna danser" ?

Tags: conjugaison, infinitif

I'm a bit confused as to why the inifinive form of "danser" is used in the phrase from the title.

I'd imagine that "Je regarde Anna danse" would be correct, as Anna is performing the action of the very and thus I would conjugate the verb to show that. Obviously this is incorrect, but could someone explain why?

Answer (score 6):

> Je regarde Anna danser.

*Je regarde* = proposition principale

*Anna danser* = proposition infinitive

In this type of sentences the verb in *la proposition principale* is usually a verb of perception (regarder, voir, entendre, écouter...). Both the proposition principale and the proposition infinitive contain a subject (*je*, *Anna*) and a verb (*regarde*, *danser*). Other examples of such constructions could be: *J'entends le train siffler. Nous regardons les avions s'éloigner dans la nuit.*

You're right that * *Je regarde Anna danse* is incorrect, however it is possible to say:

> Je regarde Anna qui danse.

What is then the difference between *Je regarde Anna danser* and *Je regarde Anna qui danse*? 
The first sentence emphasizes the action (dancing), while the second one emphasizes the actor (Anna).

Answer (score 2):

Je vais développer la réponse de @Paracosmiste

Une phrase simple ou encore proposition n'a qu'un verbe conjugué et s'il en contient plusieurs, tous les autres se mettent à l'infinitif.

**NOTE**

Les **auxiliaires** `avoir` et `être` échappent à cette règle.

En plus

`Je regarde Anna danser` a deux verbes : **regarder** et **danser**. *Danser* étant le 2me verbe de la proposition (qui dans ce cas est une phrase), se met à l'infinitif.

Pour utiliser ta formulation, on peut ajouter une **virgule** pour obtenir `Je regarde Anna, danse` et là on obtient deux propositions et une énonciation **totalement** différente en ce sens que celui qui parle demande à son interlocuteur de danser pendans qu'il regarde Anna entrain de danser.

**En résumé**

Plusieurs verbes d'une phrase simple ne peuvent être tous conjugués (à l'exception des auxiliaires). Dans le cas où il y'aurait plus d'un, les suivants se mettent à l'infinitif.

**EDIT**

I think this grammar rule also applies in English. In a `phrase simple` or `proposition` having many verbs, only the first is conjugated, all the others stay in infinitive form. This doesn't apply to `auxiliaires` which are used to conjugate verbs in `temps composés`

Answer (score 1):

Deux verbes se suivent, le deuxième se met à l'infinitif.

Comment: mais un prénom suive la preimiere verb, non?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose ça ne change rien : «Je regarde cette belle femme danser». Ce sont deux verbes dans une phrase simple.

Comment: C'est une règle que j'ai déjà entendue, mais je l'ai toujours trouvé un peu *mécanique* (du point de vue d'un natif). La bonne compréhension de la phrase me semble suffire, car c'est comme de dire :* "je regarde cette belle femme (en train de) danser"*

Answer (score 0):

In French, infinitive (*infinitif*) means "action", whereas past participle (*participe passé*) means "state".

There are people saying that there is a rule about two successive verbs inside a simple sentence, but it doesn't really help: an adjective can be made with a *participe passé*.

In English, you would translate "I'm watching Anna dancing", using the continuous present, marking the idea of action.

Comment: *participe passé* is *past participle*, not preterit.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.