# The use of infinitive instead of vu + infinitive

Tags: grammaire

I came across this sentence:

> Depuis l'arrivée d'Elon Musk à la tête de X, de nombreux scientifiques ont vu redoubler le harcèlement de la part de climatosceptiques

while reading an article and couldn't understand the usage of the infinitive (redoubler) in this context over the past participle. Fruthemore is there a specific phrasing where voir + verb can create a meaning of like seeing an increase or see a change.

P.s.: is this an impersonal construction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is danser not conjugated in "Je regarde Anna danser" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37495/why-is-danser-not-conjugated-in-je-regarde-anna-danser)

Comment: The rule is that when there are two verbs in a row the second one is in the infinitive except if the fist one is *être* or *avoir*. The linked question doesn't answer your question about "voir + verb can create a meaning", but this is really a different question ans we are supposed to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @None Sometimes, it might be tougher to grasp: *Je l'ai vu écrit* ≠ *Je l'ai vu écrire*.

Comment: @None On ne peut pas faire volontairement _j'ai vu redoublées les mauvaises nouvelles..._ d'une façon poétique, _redoublées_ étant accordé avec _nouvelles_? Ce serait un ordre des mots différents pour _j'ai vu les mauvaises nouvelles redoublées_. Au delà des règles, je ne trouve pas ça entièrement choquand, ou pour ainsi dire, je peux inventer une histoire pour le justifier :-)

Comment: Quoique, ça serait un peu bizarrre. J'essayais de faire quelque chose comme _J'ai vu rouges les pommes et vertes les prairies_, mais ça ne marche pas trop :-)

Comment: @jlliagre _Je les ai vues rouges, mais vertes les prairies_? Ça marche un peu mieux comme ça. Donc _je les ai vues écrites sur la porte_ ??? hmmm - je sens un problème dans ce double accord :-)

Comment: @Frank *Je l'ai vu écrit dans le journal*  / *Je l'ai vu écrire sur le journal* :-)

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, le sens est bien différent, mais je veux jouer avec ton premier exemple. Pour le double accord, je peux le maintenir avec une virgule: _Je les ai vues, écrites sur la porte, ces magnifiques phrases..._ :-)

Comment: @Frank Un participe passé sans auxiliaire est techniquement un adjectif, on ne peut donc pas dire qu'on est dans le cas de deux verbes qui se suivent.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, je triche :-) Dans _je les ai vues écrites_, on fait les deux accords?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147922/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-frank).

Comment: @Mifaas I don't get the question title and don't see how it's related to the Q body. FYI, you cannot replace "vu + infinitive" by just an infinitive in your sentence, it wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

*Voir* + infinitive is part of the [verbs of perception](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-of-perception/) construction. It can be used with other infinitives, nothing to do with an increase and it's not necessarily impersonal.

*J'ai vu danser les filles* - I saw the girls dancing.

*Nous avons vu tomber l'arbre* - We saw the tree fall.